# Django - Upload Image with the current user (Loggedin)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How do I save an Image in a specific folder, depending of whom is Loggedin?
My program creates a folder for every user that registers
after they login, they are able to upload some images.

The problem is when I try to save my image, I need to specify the path where is going to be Uploaded (with the userID)

Example:

If Bob is Loggedin, you will upload the images here: space/users/bob123/example.png

**Model**

```
class StudentPhotos(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to= ??? , default="", null=True)
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null=False, editable=False, default=id_generator, primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null=False, default="")
```

The main reason to save it that way is to be able to bring in my admin site all images from an user

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your model like as follows(Demonstration only):

```
class StudentPhotos(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=name)
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Here **name** (upload_to=name) can be function as follows:

```
def name(instance, fname):
     return '/'.join(instance.user.get_full_name(), fname)
```

I personally make use of **easy-thumbnails** for the purpose of having image fields in my models and I am able to use name function in the way I have given above.

Hope, you can infer some relative information and be able to come up with a better solution for your needs.